# Android ListView with adapter added programmatically cast issue

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android-adapter

I'm trying to implement a ListView in android project. I'm also really new to android and not very confortable with android xml .. That's why I prefer to do almost everthing in code :)

I have created my activity with my ListView and also the adapter.
It works fine on my simulator but when I try to debug on my device (Xperia T3) the app crash when trying to display result in listview i guess..

This is my code.

```
public void InitActivity(int width){
    this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    this.listViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(this.getContext());

    this.listView = new ListView(this.getContext());
    this.listView.setAdapter(this.listViewAdapter);

    this.addView(this.listView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}
```

And the adapter getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = parent.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = displayMetrics.density;

    LinearLayout listLayout = new LinearLayout(this.context);
    listLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    listLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (70 * dp)));        

    // ... Add some others views

    return listLayout;
}
```

But when running the app i'm getting this error :

```
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.two4tea.fightlist, PID: 6424
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1195)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1277)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1187)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1238)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:306)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5129)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16650)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5625)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:613)
01-07 14:27:23.648 6424-6424/com.two4tea.fightlist E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: could you please post your xml

Comment: are you trying to set a `LayoutManager` for the `ListView`? or you are trying to build the `View` programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In your Imports in java code

Use

```
   import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams
```

instead of the

```
   import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams
```

Comment: In the adapter.java file ?

Answer (score 0):

When adding the view, don't use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` but `AbsListView.LayoutParams`.